# Как запустить executor тг бота в асинхронной функции? Python, aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть такой код:

```
import logging
import asyncio

from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from tg_bot.config import load_config

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format=u'%(filename)s:%(lineno)d #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s')
    config = await load_config('.env')
    bot = Bot(token=config.tg_bot.token, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
    storage = MemoryStorage()
    dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, storage=storage)

    # await dp.start_polling()
    executor.start_polling(skip_updates=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Мне нужно запустить цикл, я знаю, что есть функция dp.start_polling(), но мне нужно скипать апдейты, которые могут приходить во время отключения бота. Это можно прописать в executor.start_polling(skip_updates=True), но у меня не получается запустить executor в асинхронной функции. Как можно это сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `on_startup` параметр в `executor.start_polling()` для запуска асинхронной функции при старте бота, а затем запустить вашу задачу с помощью метода `create_task` библиотеки `asyncio`

```
async def my_func():
    while True:
        print('Task is running')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup(dp):
    asyncio.create_task(my_func())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

В этом примере, мы создаем асинхронную функцию `my_func()`, которая будет выполняться в цикле, и используем `on_startup` параметр в `executor.start_polling()` для запуска этой функции при старте бота. Затем мы используем метод `create_task` библиотеки asyncio для запуска задачи.
Надеюсь, это поможет вам запустить асинхронный цикл с пропуском обновлений в aiogram!